# draggable/droppable not updating database when using with location.reload(true)

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I'm working on creating a bottling calendar that updates a database.  But I'm having some problems with the draggable and droppable functionality.  I want the screen to reload after I drag a bottling from one date to another, but whenever I put in location.reload(true) this stops the dropped function from working, if I take location.reload(true) out, and then refresh manually after dragging and dropping then it works fine.

http://hq.terravant.com/calendar/calendar.php

```
$(function() {
    $( ".draggable" ).draggable();
    $( ".droppable" ).droppable({
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
        // $( this ).addClass( "ui-state-highlight" ).find( "p" ).html( "Dropped!" ); 

            var droppableId = $( this).attr("id");

                   var draggableId = ui.draggable.attr("id");
                    var objText = ui.draggable.text(); 

              $.post("update_bottling.inc.php",
               {
                dbID:draggableId,
                newDate:droppableId,
                prodId:objText
              },
              function(data,status){
               // alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
              });

              location.reload(true);  // reloads the screen this isn't working
        }  // ends the drop function

    }); // ends the droppable function

    $(".draggable").click(function(){
        var dragId = $(this).attr('id');
        var prodId = $(this).text();


              $.post("details.inc.php",
              {
                date:dragId,
                productId:prodId
              },
              function(data){
                $('#details').html(data);
              });     
    });  // end the draggable click function

});  // ends the on ready function
```

Comment: Removing the php tag as this is not php related. If I made a mistake, update your question to include problematic PHP code and readd the tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working on chrome v36.0.1985.143.
After dragging a product into a .droppable zone the page refreshes as expected.

Anyway try updating your code into: 
window.location = ""; 
instead of

window.location.reload(true);

Comment: That seems to be working for me in Chrome as well.  I guess I can just make all the users use that.